# Azure app or cloud service, run some code before load balncer

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-web-app-service

In case of Cloud Service in Azure (maybe also App Service), how can I run some code before the service become available in swap or in case of new instance.

for example, loading data to cache before the first user have access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Cloud Services with Roles

Place your app init code inside `OnStart()`.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.onstart.aspx:

```cs
public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
   public override bool OnStart()
   { 
      try
      {
         // Add initialization code here
      } 
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         Trace.WriteLine("Exception during OnStart: " + e.ToString());
         // Take other action as needed.
      }

      return base.OnStart();
   }
}
```

> Before the `OnStart` method returns, the status of the role instance is set to Busy and the instance is not available through the load balancer.
>
> If the `OnStart` method returns false, the role instance is immediately stopped. If the method returns true, Windows Azure starts the role by calling the Run method. In general, you should avoid returning false from the `OnStart` method.

#### App Service

Use the [Application Initialization](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization) IIS module. The mechanism is described in detail here - http://ruslany.net/2015/09/how-to-warm-up-azure-web-app-during-deployment-slots-swap/

*web.config*:

```xml
<system.webServer>  
  <applicationInitialization >  
    <add initializationPage="/warmup-cache.php" hostName="site.azurewebsites.net"/>  
  </applicationInitialization>  
<system.webServer>
```

Comment: when I do the second option in cloud service it's get stack, locally.

Comment: What should be the "hostname" in local enviourement ?

Comment: I don't know if the emulator can handle that feature. What happens if you deploy it to Azure, does it behave as expected? To answer your question, _hostname_ is whatever you have after `http://` when you point a browser to your HTTP endpoint - probably `localhost` or `ComputerName`.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your answers. I will wait one more day to see if some one know another option. Locally the IIS process itself throw an error and shut down with the "applicationInitialization".

Comment: I test the WebRole solution locally and it seems like the site is available before the WebRole.OnStart is finished.
Is there a way to promise availability only after a certain command ?

Comment: Again, in the emulator things are VERY different. Test with a staging deployment in Azure, do not test on your machine.

Comment: @evilSnobu is application initialization not available for cloud service?