# Azure, Cloud Service, How to warm up the service before the loadbalancer

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I was trying to run a demo request in the WebRole class OnStart function.
Just to make all the caches to load, but still the first request I send to the service takes almost a minute and the next one is last than a second.

I was thinking that it is the IIS that doing something heavy on the first request.

Some idea how to warm up the service ?
This is a different request than just running some code before Loadbalancer, which is not sufficient to warm up the service.

The problem is off course when the service is scaling out with a new instance, and the first user to use it will wait a very long time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure app or cloud service, run some code before load balncer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39943566/azure-app-or-cloud-service-run-some-code-before-load-balncer)

Comment: This is a different request than just running some code before Loadbalancer, which is not sufficient to warm up the service, as I explained.